# Javascript x Ajax x html x jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache-cordova

Por favor, preciso de uma ajuda. Estou tentando desenvolver um aplicativo com ***phonegap*** x ***html*** x ***jquery*** x ***javascript*** e ***Ajax***, tenho a seguinte situação:

Estou em uma página, aps o usuário entrar com  email e senha, chamo o ***ajax***, de uma página externa para validar, em  ***js***. Conforme abaixo:

### Item 1:

```
$('form').submit(function() {    
console.log( "submit!" );
var postData = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: postData,
        url: 'http://localhost/service/service_usu.php',
        success: function(data){
            //alert('ret:'+data);
                if (data!='11') {
                    //alert('usuario nao validado!');                               
                    window.location='http://localhost/usu_incons.html';
                }           
                if (data=='11') {
                    alert('usuario validado!');
                    //window.location='http://localhost/inc_usu_ok.html';
                }           
        },
        error: function(){
            //console.log(data);
            alert('There was an error adding your comment');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Perfeito, realiza o check do usuário e quando negativo chama a página `usu_incons.html`, e nesta página mostra o motivo da inconsistência e tem um botão voltar: `<a id="voltar" href="index.html" data-role="button">Usu&aacute;rio ou email inexistente!</a>`

Perfeito, ele volta para a página `index.html`. Nesta página `index.html` o botão do ***javascript*** do item 1 acima não funciona mais, já tentei o **item 3** abaixo e nada....... não sei o que fazer para que possa informar novamente o email e senha e chamar o ***js***/***ajax*** novamente.

### item 3:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  app.initalize;
  app.receivedEvent;
  console.log( "ready!" );
});
var app = {

        initialize: function() {
            this.bindEvents();
            //console.log( "entrou initialize" );
        },

        bindEvents: function() {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
            $(document).on("pagecontainershow", app.onDeviceReady);
        },

        onDeviceReady: function() {
            app.receivedEvent('deviceready')
        },

        receivedEvent: function(id){

            alert($.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('getActivePage').data('http://localhost/usu_incons.html'));

        }

}
```

Comment: Cadê a action do botão?

Comment: Utilizar o botão submit com ajax pode gerar muitos problemas. Geralmente quando uso ajax troco o botão submit pelo input type button. Imagino que seu form não tenha uma action, ja que está usando ajax. Entao o form pode estar recarregando a pagina sem vc perceber.

Answer (score 1):

Tente o seguinte

Inclua no botão submit uma ação de toque/clique, execute isto no momento do `"deviceready"`

```
//exemplo
jQuery("#id_do_submit").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //para evitar que execute algo...
    //seu código aqui
});
```

Com isso vc garante que toda vez que o botão for clicado uma ação será executada.

Claro que vc precisa cuidar para não executar várias vezes no caso de um usuário pressionar o botão várias vezes...

^^V